# Unexplainable change in C variable

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I've written a simple C program to convert `char` into `Token`s. Things work fine but I'm unable to understand why the `size` variable value is changing.

```
typedef struct _token {
    int val;
} Token;

void parse( char* code, int size, Token** tokens ) {
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < size; i++) {
        tokens[i] = malloc(sizeof(Token));
        tokens[i]->val = code[i];  
    }
}

int execute( char *path ) {
    char* code;
    if ( read_file( path, &code ) != 0 ) {
        return -1;
    }
    int size = strlen(code) - 1;
    printf("BEFORE PARSE: %d\n", size);    // 1st printf
    Token *tokens;
    parse( code, size, &tokens );        
    printf("AFTER PARSE: %d\n", size);     // 2nd printf
    return 0;
}
```

if `code` contains `"abcde"`, the output is:

```
BEFORE PARSE: 5
AFTER PARSE: 142786584
```

The second `printf` displays different values on different runs.

Please help !

PS: I'm a C noob !

**EDIT:**

```
int read_file(char* path, char** code) {
    FILE* fp = fopen ( path , "rb" );
    if( !fp ) {
        return -1;
    }

    fseek( fp , 0L , SEEK_END);
    long lSize = ftell( fp );
    rewind( fp );

    /* allocate memory for entire content */
    *code = calloc( 1, lSize+1 );
    if( !*code ) {
        fclose( fp );
        return -1;
    }

    /* copy the file into the buffer */
    if( 1 != fread( *code , lSize, 1 , fp) ) {
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }

    fclose( fp );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need malloc tokens before you call parse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typical case of buffer overflow.

```
char* code;
```

Allocates a pointer to character (typically 8 bytes), not a buffer to hold your file data.

Same with

```
Token *tokens;
```

When you write to `tokens` in `parse` you overwrite part of your stack and `size` with it.

Allocate enough memory for them!

```
char * code = malloc(0x1000);
Token *tokens = malloc(0x100 * sizeof(Token *));
```

And pass the pointer, not it's address:

```
read_file( path, code );
parse( code, size, tokens );
```

Here is corrected code:

```
typedef struct _token {
    int val;
} Token;

void parse( char* code, int size, Token* tokens ) {
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < size; i++) {
            // you already have memory now
        tokens[i]->val = code[i];  
    }
}

int execute( char *path ) {
    char* code =  malloc(0x1000);
    if ( read_file( path, code ) != 0 ) {
        return -1;
    }
    int size = strlen(code) - 1;
    printf("BEFORE PARSE: %d\n", size);    // 1st printf
    Token *tokens = calloc(sizeof(Token), 0x100);
    parse( code, size, tokens );        
    printf("AFTER PARSE: %d\n", size);     // 2nd printf
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are right about Tokens, but it looks to me like code is probably being changed to point to a buffer allocated in read_file() - that would be consistent with the style of implementation used in execute()

Comment: @ChrisStratton May be. He didn't supply the code for read_file, so I can't tell for sure. It would be rather unusual though.

Comment: It's the logical explanation for the use of the & operator, and stylistically consistent with the code which has been supplied.  Also, even if you were somehow right, that couldn't be the cause of the problem experienced, which only occurs later.

Answer (score 4):

It is because tokens is never initialized. Change it to:

```
Tokens **tokens = malloc(sizeof(Tokens *) * size);
```

Don't forget to free the memory when you are done with it:

```
for (; i < size; i++) {
    free(tokens[i]);
}

free(tokens);
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to call `free(tokens[i])`? You're passing a struct instead of a pointer. Also you could have been warned that you are only calling `malloc()` once but `free()` in a loop. That way they can't ever match.

Comment: Also `sizeof (Tokens *)` is wrong when allocating an array whose elements are of type `Token`, not `Token *`.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda inside `parse()` he is allocating the individual Token structures: `tokens[i] = malloc(sizeof(Token));` so `tokens` is an array of `Token *`. But yes, to be correct, `tokens` should be declared as `Token **` and he will also need to update how `parse` accesses it.

Comment: Now it makes sense. I would take precaution, though, especially when posting an example to make it work correctly. Without the unwritten initialization, I'd probably prefer `calloc()` to zero-fill the pointer array. Otherwise I would include the initialization loop in the example.